# Kendo Scheduler Task color

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I want to use Different colors for different values of a Particular Property into ViewModel.

My ViewModel is as::

```
public class SchedulerViewModel : ISchedulerEvent
{
    public string ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public int? RecurrenceID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
    public string RecurrenceException { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
    public string StartTimezone { get; set; }
    public string EndTimezone { get; set; }
    public int IsDismissed { get; set; }

}
```

And on View I am using following::

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Invoice.Models.ViewModels.SchedulerViewModel>()
        .Name("scheduler")
        .StartTime(DateTime.UtcNow)
        .AutoBind(true)
        .Date(DateTime.UtcNow)
        .Views(views =>
        {
            views.DayView(dateformat => dateformat.SelectedDateFormat("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}"));
            views.WeekView(weekview => weekview.Selected(true));
            views.MonthView();
            views.AgendaView();
        })

        .Resources(resource =>
        {
                        resource.Add(m => m.IsDismissed)
                               .Title("Is Dismissed")
                               .DataValueField("Value")
                               .DataColorField("Color")
                               .BindTo(new[] {
                                new { Value = 1, Color = "#f8a398" } ,            //red
                                new {Value = 0, Color = "#51a0ed" }              //Blue
                            });
        })

        .DataSource(d => d
            .Batch(false)
            .Model(m =>
            {
                m.Id(f => f.ScheduleID);
                m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
                m.Field(f => f.IsDismissed).DefaultValue(0);
                m.Field(f => f.Start).DefaultValue(DateTime.UtcNow);
                m.Field(f => f.End).DefaultValue(DateTime.UtcNow);
            })
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Read("Calendar_ReadSchedule", "Dispatch")
            .Create("Calendar_CreateSchedule", "Dispatch")
            .Destroy("Calendar_DestroySchedule", "Dispatch")
            .Update("Calendar_UpdateSchedule", "Dispatch")

    )
)
```

The Problem is that I am getting only the default color as red for tasks in Scheduler.
But I want different colors based on the Value in property 'IsDismissed'.

How can it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(function() {
   scheduler_update();
});


function scheduler_update()
{
    var calendarResources = [ {  "text": "Calendar ONE", "value": "mycalendar1", "color": "#9fc6e7" },{  "text": "Calendar TWO", "value": "mycalendar2", "color": "#7bd148" }];

    var calendarFilters = {logic: "or", filters: [ { "field": "value", "operator": "eq", "value": "mycalendar1" },{ "field": "value", "operator": "eq", "value": "mycalendar2" }]};

    schedulerTasks = [{"Id": "task1","Title": "Task 1","Description": null,"CalendarId": "mycalendar1","StartDate": "2014-03-19 08:00","EndDate": "2014-03-19 09:00","IsAllDay": false},
                  {"Id": "task2","Title": "Task 2","Description": null,"CalendarId": "mycalendar2","StartDate": "2014-03-19 10:00","EndDate": "2014-03-19 11:00","IsAllDay": false}];
    var schedulerControl = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    schedulerControl.resources[0].dataSource.data(calendarResources);
    schedulerControl.resources[0].dataSource.filter(calendarFilters);
    schedulerDataSource.read();
    schedulerControl.view(schedulerControl.view().name);
}
```

**[Demo](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@Iliana/eBUb)**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe youre databinding is not korrekt and as a result all events get defaultvalue

add event to scheduler:
...
.Events(events => events
        .DataBound("scheduler_dataBound"))
...
and function in javascript:
 function scheduler_dataBound(e) {
 scheduler._data.forEach(function (name) { console.log( " id " +name.id+ " uid "+name.uid) });

}
...
in youre case 
scheduler._data.forEach(function (name) { console.log( "isDis " + name.IsDismissed)

to debug the events mabey this can help u to detect the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EventTemplate property to color the background of your events.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Invoice.Models.ViewModels.SchedulerViewModel>()
        .Name("scheduler")
        .StartTime(DateTime.UtcNow)
        .AutoBind(true)
        .EventTemplate( "<div style= 'background-color:( #= IsDismissed # );'>" +
                        "<h3>#= title #</h3>" +
                    "</div>")
```